# Difference between >> and >>>

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What's the difference between `>>` and `>>>` in Verilog/SystemVerilog?

I know that `==` tests for only `1` and `0` while `===` tests for `1`,`0`,`X`,`Z`. So how is that similar to the shift operator?